# Merge collections in different databases in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have simple ranking system written in nodejs which is based on mongodb database. For each month system creates different database: ranking-1 for Janurary, ranking-2 for February etc.
Now I need to sum each user points from six months. From July to December.

In each database I have collection named users which contains user model which looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    id: Number,
    name: String,
    points: Number,
    avatar: String,
    rank: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Now I would like to find user by id and sum his points from six months and export this data to another database or collection.

Ranking for december is still updating so I need to process this task every 15 minutes.

I know there is map and reduce but if I understand it well it is working on collections at the same database?

Is there a way to merge this data or I need to rebuild whole system?

Comment: The only way (that I'm aware of) that you can query data across different collections is using the $lookup operator.  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/ Ok, there's graphLookups, too, which you presumably don't need, though. If you post some sample data, I might be able to help you.

Comment: I initially misread your question, I'm sorry. You're asking about cross database (!) queries, not cross collection queries...

Comment: So there is no hope? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way using MongoDB to query data across databases.

And, frankly, unless you have really good reasons to go with that custom "by month" partitioning, I would not recommend doing so. So if you can change your system to keep everything in one database (and probably even one collection) then that's certainly the way to go.

However, I can think of a bunch of workarounds:

1. If it's really just a single sum that you need to calculate then you could write a small application that simply accesses all relevant 6 databases in a row to calculate the partial sums and then sums up the 6 return values into the final result. That should be trivial and would probably be the way to go (unless you can merge your databases)
2. You create some script that calls [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) (probably with the `query` parameter to limit your data to what's really needed) to extract the information from your relevant databases/collections and [mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/) to restore them into a common database (ideally even into the same target collection). Then you can run normal queries against that new collection.
3. You could get Apache Spark, set up all your data sources and have Spark do the heavy lifting: https://databricks.com/blog/2015/03/20/using-mongodb-with-spark.html. That would be majorly over-complicating things unless you have Spark running anyway.

Comment: I will go with option 1 for now and then I need to rebuild it to store data in same database. Thank you.